# Receiving error while trying to play video with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make local video playable with AVPlayer in xcode 10.1, swift 4.2, macOS app. I have created the AVKit Player View object in UI and made outlet in viewController.swift. Also created button in where all the actions should happen. You can see the code here -

```
import Cocoa
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import AppKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var playerView: AVPlayerView!

@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let videoURL = "/Users/ramix/Downloads/test.mp4"

    let video = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: videoURL))
    let videoPlayer = AVPlayerView()
    videoPlayer.player = video

    present(videoPlayer, animator:true, completion:{
        video.play()
    })

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

}
```

I saw in multiple places that there was used AVPlayerViewController, but for some reason I dont have option to choose that method. Also this code returns this error -

Cannot invoke 'present' with an argument list of type '(AVPlayerView, animator: Bool, completion: () -> Void)'

I am new to swift, and I would like to ask for your help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you already created an outlet to an `AVPlayerView` which you probably added to the view hierarchy in Interface Builder. So you don't need to create a new player view, just assign the player to the outlet view like so:

```
self.playerView.player = video
```

Btw, the error happens because `present` is meant for presenting other view **controllers**, not for displaying views.

Comment: You should probably also store the `AVPlayer` in a property, otherwise it would get released as soon as your button click was handled.

Comment: Ok when I change to this I got this in output - 
<<<< AVOutputDeviceDiscoverySession (FigRouteDiscoverer) >>>> -[AVFigRouteDiscovererOutputDeviceDiscoverySessionImpl outputDeviceDiscoverySessionDidChangeDiscoveryMode:]: Setting device discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_Presence 
And nothing happens

Comment: This error should not be related. You also need to start playback with `videoPlayer.play`, maybe in `viewDidAppear`.